# Could threading or multiprocessing improve performance when analyzing a single string with multiple regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, multithreading, string, multiprocessing

If I want to analyze a string using dozens of regular-expressions,
could either the threading or multiprocessing module improve performance?
In other words, would analyzing the string on multiple threads or processes be faster than:

```
match = re.search(regex1, string)
if match:
    afunction(match)
else:
    match = re.search(regex2, string)
    if match:
        bfunction(match)
    else:
        match = re.search(regex3, string)
        if match:
            cfunction(match)
...
```

No more than one regular expression would ever match, so that's not a concern.
If the answer is multiprocessing, what technique would you recommend looking into (queues, pipes)?

Comment: Technically, one should be able to run them in parallel to improve *worst-case* execution time, but it should be tested. Maybe, cache-misses will make average execution time even worse.

Comment: How many regexs are we dealing with here?

Comment: @unutbu Possibly hundreds, minimally dozens, I have no way of knowing yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python threading won't improve performance because of the GIL which precludes more than one thread running at a time. If you have a multicore machine, it's possible that multiple processes may speed things up but only if the cost of spawning subprocesses and passing data around is less than the cost of performing your RE searches.

If you do this often, you might look into thread pools.

Comment: To be clear, are you referring me to [Process Pools](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)?

Comment: Yes. I phrased that wrong. The idea is, if you are repeatedly searching using subprocesses, create pools of them so that you only pay for spawning them one time. Thereafter, your main process sends them work to do as required.

Answer (score 4):

Regexes themselves are a powerful answer.  The following example can compose all the regexes into one big regex.  (In the example, substitute your regexes for `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`.

```
(a?P<A>)|(b?P<B>)|(c?P<C>)|(d?P<D>))
```

Use `lastindex` on `MatchObject` to find out the index of the group that matched.  Use `groupindex` on `RegexObject` to translate that index to regex name, which is the label in angle brackets (I used uppercase for them in the example above).

**Edit:**  (performance analysis)

In cases where the regexes involved are simple enough to correspond to regular languages and therefore be quick to match by a [finite state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_State_Automaton), this approach will actually result in a performance effect similar to parallel evaluation, surprisingly only consuming one processor resource.

The reason is that the `|` operator, alongside with `?`, `*`, `[]`, or repetition (but in contrast to most uses of backreferences) is one of operators allowed in regexes that define [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).  (Notice the "union" in the reference.)  Therefore the combined regex is also searchable by a finite state automaton, without any need to backtrack.

Finite state automatons spend only a finite number of operations on each character of the input string.  They keep a state (basically a memory pointer) that represents "potential matching progress" at the current position of the input.  In case of the combined regex, the FSA is larger and it takes longer to compile (and the memory pointer has more memory locations to point to).  But that (creating the `Regex` object) can be done once upon the startup of the application, and each subsequent input can be searched fast.

Let's compare this to a thread-based parallel execution of individual regexes.  The progress through each regex will be similar but not the same for start-of-input-anchored regexes especially because final rejections of non-matching regexes will usually be much faster than successful matches.  There is a minor advantage on the side of threads: the fastest match will allow to terminate the whole computation, whereas the combined regex has to complete evaluation of all matches (all groups).  In practice the thread pool overhead will more than offset this, and with a large number of threads it will be basically unusable.

The performance benefit of the combined regex technique is thus especially noticeable with a large number of regexes, and is paid for by increased memory consumption.

*While it meets this question's preference of parallel matching under the hood, in smaller instances like a handful of regexes it may not be worth the extra complexity of composing the regex.*

Comment: Thanks again, your suggestion really helped me rethink my approach.

Comment: @HonestAbe - You are welcome and I value your feedback too - as well as the accepted answer (+1).

Comment: I like this solution because conceptually, it should be better to do one and only one pass over the input string, instead of doing one pass per regex. In practice, if one of the regexes `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` fails then the regex engine has to backtrack anyway, but at least it short-circuits if none of them match.

Comment: @Li-aungYip - If none of the small regexes requires backtracking, neither does the big one.  At least mathematically; how the Python regex module is exactly implemented is another question, but there is no reason known to me why it should not be FSA based.  If you want, I can edit the question to clarify and provide links.  Of course, the FSA for the big regex will be bigger in memory and take longer to build.

Comment: Some clarification would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Li-aungYip - Answer extended to explain the expected performance effects. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is performance your concern? If not, just put all REs in an array and loop over it!

```
for each myRE in myListOfRE
    result = myRE.search(...)
    if result != None:
        something with sqlalchemy
        break
```

If performance is indeed a concern, I would think multi threading should help. RE match only needs read access to the string being searched, so it should be possible to share it. Though I'm not python expert so can't really tell you how to DO it.

Comment: You could potentially improve the performance of this by replacing the `for` loop with `if any((my_re.search(...) is not None for my_re in my_list_of_res)): # do something with sqlalchemy here`. [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) is optimized for this sort of case.