# Can you help me figure out why this function execution is too bad?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-re

I am trying to use threads in Python to read some files (big files, some of the might be over a Gig size) and parse the file to find specific info, I am using the re module for that.
The problem is that I'm seeing very high execution times.
Reading over 4 files, then parsing the files for my data takes me over 30 seconds. Is this expected or there's any recommendation you can provide me with to improvde these times?
I apologize in advance, I'm sure that this has been asked in the forum already, i really tried to find this myself but could not find the right words to search for this problem.

Below is my current code:

```
def get_hostname(file: str) -> str:
    """
    Get the hostname from  show tech/show running file
    :param file: show tech/show running string
    :return: the hostname as a string
    """
    hostname = re.findall('hostname.*', file, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(hostname) > 0:
        return hostname[0].split(' ')[1]
    else:
        print('Could not find a valid hostname on file ' + file)
```

```
def set_file_dictionary():
    threads_list = []
    def set_file_dictionary_thread(file_name: str):
        thread_set_file_dict_time = time.time()
        current_file = open(path + file_name, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore').read()
        files_dir[get_hostname(current_file)] = current_file
        print('set_file_dictionary_thread is ' + str(time.time() - thread_set_file_dict_time))
    for file in list_files:
        threads_list.append(threading.Thread(target=set_file_dictionary_thread, args=(file, )))
    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.join()
```

The result is

```
      set_file_dictionary_thread is 12.55484390258789
      set_file_dictionary_thread is 13.184206008911133
      set_file_dictionary_thread is 16.15609312057495
      set_file_dictionary_thread is 16.19360327720642
      Main exec time is 16.1940469741821
```

Thanks for reading me
NOTE - The indentation is ok, for some reason it gets messed up when copying from Pycharmand

Comment: Please add your `re` code.

Comment: Hey scenox did not notice that did not include my get_hostname() method (where my re code is executed). 
Basically im using a re.findall to match a specific line of my file
I added the get_function() method to the original post

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, running regex in multiple python threads won't help much. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9984414/14035728)

Secondly, you can improve your `get_hostname` function by:

1. compiling regex beforehand
2. using `search` instead of `findall`, since apparently you only need the first match
3. using `groups` to capture the hostname, instead of string `split`

Here's my suggested `get_hostname` function:

```
hostname_re = re.compile('hostname ([^ ]*)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
def get_hostname(file: str) -> str:
    match = hostname_re.search(file)
    if match:
        return match.groups()[0]
    else:
        print('Could not find a valid hostname on file ' + file)
```